# Google + Redirect URI errors

Tags: api, uri

... When creating Google API if anyone gets an error like this "Invalid Redirect URI". So below I will be posting my solution also that helped me and will save your time.

Comment: Posting more details would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find out the mystery about redirect uris myself too but as far as i know you must save the redirect uri you are using in your app into the settings of the api console. Select your project and then clik on the crdentials on the left bar. Yo ucan't miss it